# Linq group by date when using multiple group by fields

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Since linq does not allow you to use the Date() method inside a linq query, **I read about using DbFunctions.TruncateTime, which works fine until you try using it inside an anonymous type** which is what I need to do in order to group on multiple fields. I also tried creating a new datetime using just the date portion of my field but this doesn't work either (again with the same error).

My query looks like

```
kw = kw
    .GroupBy(x => new { DbFunctions.TruncateTime(g.SummaryHour), x.KeywordID })
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.KeywordID);
```

I tried chaining the group by's together like groupby.groupby... but this doesn't give me the same result. **Any way I can achieve this? I'm basically trying to filter out the time portion of my date and group by other fields as well.**

Comment: you can try use [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) with it's `DiffDays` fucntion and try to group by difference with some date

Comment: It wont let me call a method... I'm already using the equivalent which is DbFunctions.TruncateTime(g.SummaryHour) but this doesn't work with anonymous types

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites what error does it give you? Have you tried to group by year, month, day?

Comment: You can't use methods when creating anonymous types.

Comment: then try to group by `new {x.Year, x.Month, x.Day ....}`

Comment: This would give me three groupings. I only want to group by date. You can't create a new datetime either using the year month and day as you get the same error as when calling truncate time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure you can use a method in an anonymous type, but you have to supply the name of the property, because the compiler doesn't have anything to derive it from:

```
kw.GroupBy(x => new { 
                      Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(g.SummaryHour),
                      x.KeywordID
                    })
```

Comment: Bazinga. That was the magic ticket.